# Apply CSS style to only first <iframe> body

Tags: css

I've been trying to make the pages grayer. White backgrounds bother me a lot.

So I use the Stylus add-on to add this code bellow to every page I visit.

The problem is with pages with iframes/multiple body elements, because they all get this code and get darker and darker.

I've tried body:first-of-type with no success.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

```
body:first-of-type:before {
    content: "";
    position: fixed;
    top: 450%;
    left: 0%;
    outline: 600000000000px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
    z-index: 100000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use document.querySelector('iframe') to target the first iframe and add an event listener "load" to make sure the iframe will load first before triggering the addition of CSS style.

Your code would be probably something like this.

```js
const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
if (iframe) {
  iframe.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const css = 'body:before { content: ""; position: fixed; top: 450%; left: 0%; outline: 600000000000px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .30); z-index: 100000000; }';
    const style = iframe.contentDocument.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.appendChild(iframe.contentDocument.createTextNode(css));
    iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(style);
  });
}
```

Comment: Actually I'd like to get the main body of the page and not the ones that are 'children' of iframes. The question title was edited and is not representing what I'd like.

Comment: Do you see somehow I could use only CSS? By your code I'd have to use some javascript injector

Comment: Hmm.. I think you can try any of this. 

"body:not(iframe body):before"
or
":root > body:first-of-type:before"

Comment: Both can be used, but ":root > body:first-of-type:before" targets only the first body element that is a direct child of the :root element, while "body:not(iframe body):before" targets any body element that is not within an iframe.